# TeamCity show branch in artifact zip name

Tags: git, teamcity, branch

I have a build in TeamCity where I want to build an artifact zip file.

I can use `Edit Configuration Settings => General Settings => Artifact Paths` to set up the files to zip and the zip file name.

I want to make the name more descriptive, and TeamCity lets me use parameters, e.g. :

```
out/mypackagedfiles/** => MyBuild_%build.number%.zip
```

will give me a zip file like `MyBuild_46.zip`.

I'd also like to include the branch that the build was built from. This is also available as a TeamCity parameter, but it contains a forward slash (e.g. `feature/my_great_feature`).  So if I use this in the `Artifact Paths` configuration, I get a directory containing a zip file:

```
out/mypackagedfiles/** => MyBuild_%build.number%_%vcsroot.branch%.zip
```

which gives `my_great_feature.zip` in a directory called `MyBuild_46_feature`.

What I'd like to do is somehow remove/replace the forward slash from the branch name to get one zip file, such as `MyBuild_46_feature_my_great_feature.zip`.

I'm not to worried about the exact format - as long as the branch name is identifiable.

Ideas for what might exist - but I can't find yet:

- create a new parameter that derives the sanitised branch name from `vcsroot.branch`
- some kind of string manipulation within the `Artifact Paths` configuration

**== EDIT ==**

Based on oryades answer below (which looks like *linux bash* command line), I converted this to *PowerShell for Windows* as follows:

1. Set up artifacts to use %env.branch_name% (this also requires setting a temporary/dummy value in the Parameters tab for the build to run)
2. Create a build step with runner type = PowerShell
3. Set script to Source Code and paste in the following:

   ```
   $branch_name="%vcsroot.branch%".replace('/','_')
   echo "Sanitised branch for Artifact zip = " $branch_name
   echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.branch_name' value='$branch_name']"
   ```

Note that TeamCity lets you do substitution of %vcsroot.branch% - this is a substitution that happens before PowerShell runs. Thanks to [Team City and Power Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012318/team-city-and-power-shell) for this tip

Comment: I had to use `%teamcity.build.branch%` instead, to get the correct branch of the current build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create env variable during build, just create a build step with the following content:

```
branch_name=$(echo %vcsroot.branch% | sed 's/\//_/')
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.branch_name' value='$branch_name']"
```

On next build steps you can use %env.branch_name% as a variable with required value.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity

Comment: Thanks  this is brilliant. I converted this to a PowerShell version in an edit to the original question above, as that suited me better.